# Asterisk - Twilio SIP Trunking Service

Tags: twilio, sip, sip-server

I am using asterisk 16.2.1 and have setup an SIP server in my local. I have done this to enable SIP trunk calling using Twilio's platform. What configurations do I need to make on my asterisk SIP server?

I have not been able to find any good documentation which shares details on integrating the local asterisk SIP server with Twilio SIP Trunk call service.

The [documentation](https://assets.cdn.prod.twilio.com/documents/TwilioElasticSIPTrunking-AsteriskPBX-Configuration-Guide-Version2-1-FINAL-09012018.pdf?_ga=2.80404062.897774525.1705667798-542583418.1705667798&_gl=1*18r3p04*_ga*NTQyNTgzNDE4LjE3MDU2Njc3OTg.*_ga_RRP8K4M4F3*MTcwNTY2Nzc5OC4xLjEuMTcwNTY2NzgzNi4wLjAuMA..) is outdated as the parameters being set here are not currently available on Twilio SIP Trunk Console

Comment: I checked through the doc and the screenshots seem to match the Twilio Console. Which parts/steps are missing or out-of-date?